# Create multi dimensional array from array of arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have an array of arrays which is shown below

```
   Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [from] => 1
        [to] => c961c734-eae2-4fea-86bf-d543c57b0ab0
        [fromPort] => bottom0
        [toPort] => top0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [from] => 1
        [to] => 651e505c-7e24-4646-8fe0-59b4ee58f078
        [fromPort] => bottom1
        [toPort] => top0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [from] => 1
        [to] => eb4d76ca-f819-4828-95d3-777e0a4bf748
        [fromPort] => bottom2
        [toPort] => top0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [from] => c961c734-eae2-4fea-86bf-d543c57b0ab0
        [to] => 008feb2f-0361-4d94-8559-8ea5074d1c59
        [fromPort] => bottom0
        [toPort] => top0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [from] => c961c734-eae2-4fea-86bf-d543c57b0ab0
        [to] => 86a11097-a9a7-4d84-8ffc-c9c382326f51
        [fromPort] => bottom1
        [toPort] => top0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [from] => 008feb2f-0361-4d94-8559-8ea5074d1c59
        [to] => 2707bd40-d421-400d-ba55-694632facadd
        [fromPort] => bottom0
        [toPort] => top0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [from] => 008feb2f-0361-4d94-8559-8ea5074d1c59
        [to] => 307e97e0-be81-4644-b842-dcd23e88d09f
        [fromPort] => bottom1
        [toPort] => top0
    )

 )
```

What i want to achieve is create multidimensional array from above given array of arrays by keeping from and to property of each array in consideration such that ,as you can see from the arrays 1 is the parent of

```
    1) c961c734-eae2-4fea-86bf-d543c57b0ab0
    2) 651e505c-7e24-4646-8fe0-59b4ee58f078
    3) eb4d76ca-f819-4828-95d3-777e0a4bf748
```

and then

```
    c961c734-eae2-4fea-86bf-d543c57b0ab0
```

which is child of 1,is also a parent of

```
    86a11097-a9a7-4d84-8ffc-c9c382326f51
```

so i want an array that looks like this

```
   Array
   (
   [1] => Array
    (
    [c961c734-eae2-4fea-86bf-d543c57b0ab0]=>Array(        (
                               [86a11097-a9a7-4d84-8ffc-c9c382326f51]=>Array()
                                                 ),
    [651e505c-7e24-4646-8fe0-59b4ee58f078]=>Array(),
    [eb4d76ca-f819-4828-95d3-777e0a4bf748]=>Array()
    

    )
   )
```

This is What i have tried so far

```
$finalArr=array();
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($linkArr);$i++) {
    if($linkArr[$i]['from']=='1') {
        $finalArr[$linkArr[$i]['from']][$linkArr[$i]['to']]=[];
    }
}
```

I am only able to store all the children of 1 but not for others

Comment: Did you start writing anything to get you to your goal yet, if so please show.

Comment: @RiggsFolly see the edited question